# RewriteRules in my .htaccess are not working on Magento EE 1.12

Tags: .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

I have one project and it upgrade:

- Magento EE 1.9
- Magento EE 1.12

I'm working with Ubuntu. The configuration of both project is almost the same, I have the same configuration for the vhost (only the name is different) and the same .htaccess with the same permissions for both. My problem is that RewriteRules are not working on the upgrade (Magento EE 1.12) and I don't know why.
These are the rewrites in my .htaccess located in the root of the project:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^brand/(.+)$ brand-filter.html?brand=$1&%1 [L]
```

This is working on my Magento EE 1.9 but no in my Magento EE 1.12.

If I change the rewrite to another file in root directory it works, for example:

```
RewriteRule ^brand/(.+)$ test.php [L]
```

But it's not working for magento directories like:

```
RewriteRule ^brand/(.+)$ checkout/cart [L]
```

Any clue for this?

Comment: Are the two vhosts actually running on the same machine, i.e. the same instance of Apache?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same apache's instance.

Answer (score 1):

Activate the LogLevel for rewrite with

```
LogLevel debug rewrite:trace8
```

So you can exactly see why it's not matching.

Comment: I did what you say but I guess that log is correct:
rewrite 'brand/foo' -> 'brand-filter.html?brand=foo&'